# Syntax error using jquery ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm doing something wrong, some ideas?
console> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

```
$.ajax ({  
    url:     'php/loaders/news_loader.php',
    type:    'post',
    data:    post_data,
    success: function(request, settings)
             { 
                 if(request.trim() != '')
                 {
                     // something is wrong in the next line... 
                     $('#news').html( request + $('#news').html() ); 
                 } 
             }  
});
```

Comment: There's no error with the posted code. Run your whole script through http://jshint.com

Comment: There is no syntax error in this code. The error is probably in another part of your script.

Comment: Im sure there's a line number that accompanies there error, yes?

Comment: The line number points to: $('#news').html( request + $('#news').html() );

Comment: only the first time works fine when $('#news') is empty then i get the error

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:**

```
$.ajax ({  
    url:     'php/loaders/news_loader.php',
    type:    'post',
    data:    post_data,
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(request, settings)
             { 
                 if(request.trim() != '')
                 {
                     // something is wrong in the next line... 
                     $('#news').html( request + $('#news').html() ); 
                 } 
             }  
});
```